# Android: Get Color object from Resource

Tags: android

```
Color color = new Color(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.bus_departures_hover));
```

As seen, I am attemping to create a Color object from a resource. This ain't working though!

Answer (score 10):

What has worked for me is:

```
Color c = new Color(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourColor));
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin way (API REQUIRED 26);

```
Color.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_white))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no API constructor that receives an int http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#Color()

You may use

```
 int color= getResources().getColor(R.color.bus_departures_hover);
```

And use the color value in a setter.

Comment: The method I am to use requires a Color object though.

Comment: May I see the method you're trying yo use?

Comment: Color has only static helper methods, it makes no sense to create an object from it.

Comment: I use a Color object as an optional override when setting a custom view's values. This allows me to pass null to use the default. Bad practice?